# FTP client with vifm

Tags: ftp, vifm

How to use vifm as FTP client?

I followed instructions [here](http://wiki.vifm.info/index.php?title=How_to_browse_FTP_in_Vifm), but I'm confused. It's not intuitive. It doesn't tell where to put those script. Even [this](http://wiki.vifm.info/index.php?title=Quickstart_Tutorial#Defining_new_associations) one doesn't tell to. I've tried to put the script in `/home/user/.vifm/vifmrc` and `/home/user/.vifmrc`, it still doesn't work. Anyone can give step by step instructions?

Comment: You're referring to the step by step instructions, but probably you're not very familiar with such configuration systems. `~/.vifm/vifmrc` is the right place to put `:filetype` command, it should take effect after you restart Vifm (simplest way to do it). Then it should work when you try to open `.ftp`-file, if not post the error you get. If file opens in Vim rather than connecting to a remote host, then your configuration isn't OK. To make sure you use the right file check output of `:echo $MYVIFMRC` command in Vifm.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install curlftpfs -- `apt-get install curlftpfs`
2. Create file `<ftp-file-name>.ftp`
3. Add following text to file: `-o  user=<username>:<password> <hostname>:`
4. Start `vifm`, navigate to your .ftp file and press [enter]